# css display images horizontally

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to display images vertically 5 per row using php and I have achieved it.
I am also using a div and this seems to be creating a problem.
Images are displayed horizontally, but there seems to be a huge space between each image.

Heres the php code:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
    <?php
    // get the images for the new videos

    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numimages = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        extract($row);
        // extract youtube id

        preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $video_link,$matches);
        // $matches[ 1 ] should contain the youtube id
    ?>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id="videogallery">
                <a rel="#voverlay" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $matches[ 1 ];?>?autoplay=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer" title="<?php echo $video_title;?>">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $matches[ 1 ];?>/default.jpg" alt="<?php echo $video_title;?>" class="border_black" />
                </a>
            </div> 
        </td>
        <?php 
        $numimages++;
        if ($numimages%3 == 0) 
            echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the css:

```
    #videogallery {
    width:500px;
    zoom:1;
}
#videogallery span{
    display:block;
}
#videogallery a{
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:3px;
    width:160px;
    font:12px/18px "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0.87;
}
#videogallery a img{
    display:block;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
}
#videogallery a:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Your php code is irrelevant; what's the rendered html as seen by the browser (view source)?

Comment: `extract()` should be avoided. It ranks up there with register_globals and magic_quotes_gpc on the "stupidities of PHP" list.

Comment: Using a table for this kind of layout is very old-skool HTML. `display:-moz-inline-stack;` is un-necessary unless you want to support Firefox 2 (how many people still use that??) Also, agreed with @David: we don't need to see the PHP code; it's not relevant to the question. Show us the code that you get when you do 'view source' from the browser.

Comment: @Spudley, well, yes. That's what I said, isn't it..?

Comment: @David: yes; I said I agreed with you.  :)  (just trying to hammer the point home! ;))

Comment: @Spudley: *ahhh...* My bad..! XD

Comment: Thanx guys, got it working.
@Marc B -  why do you say to avoid extract()? Any problems with using it?

Comment: @tycoon: You're doing "select *", and then converting every single field retrieved in that query into variables. what if your DB had a field called _POST, or _GET, or _SERVER? Polluting your variable pool with arbitrary stuff is never a good idea, even if you KNOW that in this particular case it's "safe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed a few things. First, ids must be unique in html, but they are not in your document. You create `<div id="videogallery">` in a loop, so that id appears multiple times. You should change the `id` into a `class` (or remove the `div` completely).

Also `#videogallery` is set to have a width of 500 pixels, which is also the width of the containing table. If you plan to have 5 images next to each other, the width of a div (or an image) should not exceed 100 px. Reducing the width should already help you to reduce the gap between images.

It's generally not a good idea to use tables for layout, it should be possible to get the same effect without tables. That gives you more flexibility. (Determining the number of images per row should be a layout issue, not a code issue.)

Comment: So true, especially given his item container has a fixed width. Setting his item container as inline-block, and adding a CSS nth-of-type(5) rule, he could easily fine tune the visual without having to modify his code

Comment: thnx Arjan, the div was creating a problem, looping.
I removed the table as well.

Answer (score 2):

90% of that code is completely redundant.

You don't need the tables (in fact, it's considered very poor practice to use them for layout like this these days), and you don't need the wrapper `<div>` elements around your images.

Your `<a>` tags are already styled with `display:inline-block;`, so actually they should already line up horizontally without any of that stuff. Just put them next to each other, without all the extra junk, and they'll line up quite happily for you. You can use `margin` and `padding` to put any extra spacing between them that you do require.

All you need beyond that is a single wrapper `<div>` around the whole lot to enforce a fixed `width` for the whole block, so that they wrap onto new lines at the right points.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to learn to code pure css.... bt being used to tables.. changing takes time and a lot of learning. Till I learn to use css completely i try to use both .

Answer (score 0):

> there seems to be a huge space between
>   each gap.

Do you mean a 7 pixel gap?

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
```

Comment: sorry, I meant a huge space between each image

Comment: yea, i removed the table and going with only css

Answer (score 0):

you may avoid `<table>` alltogether by using div and css `float` see this http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0407.htm

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZfyRb/

Comment: doesn't even need `float` -- he's already using `inline-block`, which should do exactly what he wants... or it would do, if he wasn't messing it up with all those tables and wrapping divs.

Comment: I removed the table, ur right, i didnt need it.
Bt I need the div coz am trying to get this pop up and overlay effect when a user clicks on a video